# webassembly load time is too long

Tags: javascript, performance, webassembly

I am working with face detection model which is in `.wasm` format. I am reading and executing it in JavaScript. Everything works fine. But it takes too much time to complete the `WebAssembly.instantiate()` method with an **array buffer** output.

The `wasm` file is 8.6MB in size and it is taking 3 seconds to finish the execution after loading the file.

Application load time is delaying because of this. Is there any way to reduce the size of the `.wasm` file or improving the file execution time?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i have done gziping of the .wasm file it reduced to 7 MB but still the execution taking more than 3 second

Comment: That is load time, not execution time.

Comment: loading time is taking 10sec in wifi and 15-20 s in 4G networks. but execution is taking 3+ seconds.

Comment: don't forget about wasm-strip: https://webassembly.github.io/wabt/doc/wasm-strip.1.html

Answer (score 1):

[`WebAssembly.instantiate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/instantiate) is officially not a recommended way.

Use the newer [`WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/instantiateStreaming). This will load a wasm file more efficiently. Note that you should use a response object from `fetch()` than an ArrayBuffer to load wasm file.

Also, 8.6MB is pretty big for a wasm file. So you might still feel it is a bit slow to load. Have you compiled the project using optimization flags?

Comment: Thank you for the help and this .wasm file i got from a vendor who is not more servicing. is there any way to optimize this file with any tool ?